# AngularJS: two different ways to declare an angular object

Tags: angularjs

One seems to be using an array as the second argument:

```
 .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
```

The second one seems to be without the array:

```
 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
```

Both seems to work. Any difference?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered quite clearly in the documentation ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in code  minification process the argument names get changed and the definition array is used to define them then.

An important distinction between a normal  javascript function getting minified and an angular component is that the angular component is doing dependency injection so the actual names are critical